# beat against / on / at?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

The verb (beat), when used as an intransitive verb, comes with these three prepositions (against / on / at).

**Can these prepositions be used completely alternatively?**

For instance, 'Webster Dictionary' gives the following examples:

1- He beat at / against / on the door with his fists.

2- The waves were beating on / against the shore.

3- Nina managed to free herself and began beating at the 
   flames with a pillow.

**In 2:** is it wrong to say (The waves were beating at the shore.)

**In 3:** is it wrong to say (Nina began beating against / on the flames with a pillow.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's wrong to say that  waves beat so it follows that waves beating in also incorrect. Waves crash or break.

Comment: Those examples are mentioned in (Merriam-Webster's Advanced Learner's English Dictionary)!

Comment: I think it's great that Merriam-Webster would include it but that does not mean it is in common or everyday use.  I was trying to guide the person who set this task towards the most appropriate use of that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous areas in English where usages are not either right or wrong, but either idiomatic (the way people speak), unusual or just awkward - like clothes that don't fit properly.

In my experience, people beat **on** doors although they can throw themselves **against** doors. If I were to read that someone **beat at the door** it wouldn't bother me even if I would have said **on the door**. Both are acceptable.

As to the waves, it's possible to imagine them either **beating on** a slightly inclined shore or **beating against** cliffs. Both are idiomatic.

When he comes to flames, the use of either preposition (**against,on**) is not idiomatic. Google Books Ngram Viewer shows examples only of **beating the flames**. So a lot of people would regard the use of either preposition here as wrong.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beat+on+the+flames%2Cbeat+against+the+flames%2Cbeat+the+flames